# Burninate the [explanation] meta tag on SO

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Can we burninate the [explanation](/questions/tagged/explanation) tag on Stack Overflow? It doesn't get much more meta than that.

Comment: Until somebody names a framework after it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What explanation tag? I don't see any question tagged explanation. ;)